# PostgreSQL CREATE TABLE: weird syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

I have the following CREATE TABLE command:

```
create table user_payment_status(
    ID serial primary key,
    user_ID serial not null,
    last_pay_date time with time zone,
    next_pay_date time with time zone,
    due_days integer,
    warning_email_sent boolean not null,
    user_visible boolean not null,
    user_searchable boolean not null,
    user_on_free_plan boolean not null,
    created_at time with time zone,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user
      FOREIGN KEY(user_id) 
        REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

but I always get a misterious `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "not"` error message for the line `user_on_free_plan boolean not null,`.
It doesn't matter where I place this line into the command, the problem is always in this line. Can you help me, what am I missing here, what should be the problem?

I have a lot of similar CREATE TABLE-s, all of them are executed without any problem.

Comment: Can you provide example DB fiddle? [The following works fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=472b579533179cf989d19f1ee92af964) without the FK reference.

Comment: Probably some invisible non-ASCII characters. Try to copy & paste the code into plain text editor and back into your SQL client

Comment: don’t you by any chance have a table to schema named: `user_on_free_plan` or some  other variable with the same name? you might consider changing it to `on_free_plan` and see what happens. Since the only difference between that line and others is the column name. Moreover, I would suggest erasing the line and retyping it from scratch to make sure there aren’t any forbidden characters hidden. Your other option is to create the table without that line and then use the `add column` for altering the table.

Comment: Tried to change the name, same error occured. Turned out, that somehow a not allowed invisible character was there instead of a space.

Answer (score 1):

Works here:

---

```
create table user_payment_status
    ( id SERIAL primary key
    , user_id INTEGER not null  -- <<--
    , created_at TIMESTAMP with time zone       -- <<--
    , last_pay_date TIMESTAMP with time zone    -- <<--
    , next_pay_date TIMESTAMP with time zone    -- <<--
    , due_days integer
    , warning_email_sent boolean not null
    , user_visible boolean not null
    , user_searchable boolean not null
    , user_on_free_plan boolean not null
    -- , CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
    );
```

---

Some notes:

- The FOREIGN KEY may *refer* to a serial, but it itself should be an `int`
- the `time` fields should probably be `timestamp`s

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, dbfiddle and the idea of invisible not allowed ASCII character solved the issue:

between `on_free_plan` and `boolean` there was an ASCII "A0" character instead of ASCII "20" (space). Changed it to space, and works like a charm.

Thanks again! :-)